# Why is the equation for Intra-class correlation aligned with design effect of cluster sampling?

Tags: intraclass-correlation, survey-sampling, cluster-sample

The design effect definition ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_effect#Definition)) is:

$$
DEFF = 1+ (m-1)*ICC
$$

It is also the relationship between the variance of estimating the mean with the cluster sampling divided by the variance if the sample was a simple random sample.

ICC is defined as ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Modern_ICC_definitions%3A_simpler_formula_but_positive_bias)):

$$ICC = \frac{\sigma_\alpha^2}{\sigma_\alpha^2+\sigma_\varepsilon^2}. $$

However, I cannot find a clear proof showing why the relationship between DEFF and ICC are the ones provided above.

Either a proof or (open access!) reference will be much helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a while, especially because the original Kish's (1965) book is unavailable online for free, and strangely enough in most publications, the ICC is defined by simply rearranging elements from the DEFF formula, instead of using *within-* and *between-variance* terms.

However, [this handout](https://ocw.jhsph.edu/courses/StatMethodsForSampleSurveys/PDFs/Lecture5.pdf) from the John Hopkins School of Public Health appears to shed some light on the relationship between the ICC as defined in your post and the DEFF formula. Please navigate to the bottom of page 5, which starts with the notion of the Inter-class correlation. Page 6 shows how to rearrange the ICC formulae, and also derives variance for cluster sampling. Then on page 7, you will see its similarity with the DEFF formula.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.